# Using Liferay portlet in an external application

Tags: integration, liferay, portlet

I have a legacy web application that I want to enhance by adding a message board. Is it possible to add the message board portlet of liferay into this external application.

I am a newbie so pardon my naivity if I've overlooked something obvious.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible. Liferay is a portlet container that implements [JSR 268](http://developers.sun.com/portalserver/reference/techart/jsr168/) portlet specification. All portlets that can be installed in Liferay conform to this specification.

So, if you have a legacy application, which obviously isn't a portlet container, you can't install portlets into it.

Answer (score 3):

Embedding a portlet container in your webapp, just for being able to use Liferay's Message Boards (which isn't THAT good anyway), seems like a huge overkill...

In which language is your application written and which framework(s) do you use? Do a Google to see if there are any projects that you can start from or integrate in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Both the answers in my view are correct limburgie and kgiannakakis, still I would like to add something which may be a little useful.

There is an interesting feature of "Sharing" in liferay with which you can embed portlets as widgets into any application.

But the only catch is that Liferay Server should also be running while your Application is also running on the same or another server.

For more information on sharing you can visit this **[link](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/shari-3)**.